# Match Stage on From Table in go mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework, mgo

My mongodb collections

```
employee
{
  _id:ObjectId(),
  "emp_name":"qwert",
  "emp_id":111,
  "emp_dept":"XYZ"
  "qualification":"PHD"
}
{
_id:ObjectId(),
  "emp_name":"asdfg",
  "emp_id":121,
  "emp_dept":"XYZ"
 "qualification":"MBA"
}
department{
_id:ObjectId(),
"dept_id":11,
"dept_name":"XYZ",
"description":"decs",
}
```

My Go Code is

```
 type Employee struct {
    EmployeeName  string             `json:"emp_name" bson:"emp_name"`
    EmployeeID    int                `json:"emp_id" bson:"emp_id"`
    EmployeeDept  string             `json:"emp_dept" bson:"emp_dept"`
    EmpQualification string          `json:"qualification" bson:"quaification"` 
    EmpDepartment Department         `json:"department" bson:"department"` 
}
 type Department struct {
    DepartmentID    int                `json:"dept_id" bson:"dept_id"`
    DepartmentName  string             `json:"dept_name" bson:"dept_name"` 
    Description     string             `json:"description" bson:"description"` 
    EmployeeList    []Employee         `json:"employee_list" bson:"employee_list"`
}

collection := session.DB("db").C("department")
pipeline := collection.Pipe([]bson.M{
        {"$lookup": bson.M{
        "from":         "employee",
        "localField":   "dept_name",
        "foreignField": "emp_dept",
        "as":           "employee_list",
    }},
      {"$match": bson.M{
        "qualification": "PHD",
          }},
    })

err = pipeline.All(&departmentEmployees)
```

It shows null result

I want to get all departments from my department collection with each department has employee List of 'PHD' qualificaton. I have uploaded my collections and struct as Example.How to use match field on from table in look up.

I want to get output like

```
{
    dept_id:11,
   dept_name:'XYZ'
   description:'desc'
   employee_list:[
     {
     emp_name:"qwerty"
     emp_id:111,
     qualification:'PHD' 
     }
     {
     emp_name:"asdfg"
     emp_id:222,
     qualification:'PHD' 
     }
...
]}
 {
    dept_id:12,
   dept_name:'ABC'
   description:'descwe'
   employee_list:[
     {
     emp_name:"bjgk"
     emp_id:865,
     qualification:'PHD' 
     }
     {
     emp_name:"hkj"
     emp_id:967,
     qualification:'PHD' 
     }
...
]}
```

For First college get all employees having PHD degree then for second college and so on.I am confused either i have to use group by in from collection in lookup or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have a typo in your `Employee.EmpQualification` field's tag:

```
EmpQualification string `json:"qualification" bson:"quaification"`
```

It should be:

```
EmpQualification string `json:"qualification" bson:"qualification"`
```

Next, when you lookup employees as `employee_list`, that will be a new field in the result, so `qualification` would refer to a field of `department` and not that of an employee.

And since `employee_list` is an array, you can't simply match, you have to filter the array, and replace the `employee_list` with the new, filtered array.

Last, you might want to exclude departments without any employees with "PHD" qualification.

The final aggregation looks like this:

```
pipeline := collection.Pipe([]bson.M{
    {"$lookup": bson.M{
        "from":         "employee",
        "localField":   "dept_name",
        "foreignField": "emp_dept",
        "as":           "employee_list",
    }},
    {
        "$addFields": bson.M{
            "employee_list": bson.M{
                "$filter": bson.M{
                    "input": "$employee_list",
                    "as":    "emp",
                    "cond":  bson.M{
                        "$eq": []interface{}{"$$emp.qualification", "PHD"},
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {"$match": bson.M{
        "employee_list": bson.M{"$not": bson.M{"$size": 0}},
    }},
})
```

Also note that the above aggregation have to search all departments and their employees. A better approach would be to start from employees, filter by qualification and then group by department.

Extending the second approach: once you have the employees that have PHD, group by `emp_dept` and gather the employees in `employee_list`, then lookup the department. Then you have to "construct" the result documents, that is, the looked up department must be the "root" with an additional `emplyee_list` (gathered during the `$group` stage).

This is how it would look like:

```
pipeline := collection.Pipe([]bson.M{
    {"$match": bson.M{
        "qualification": "PHD",
    }},
    {"$group": bson.M{
        "_id":           "$emp_dept",
        "employee_list": bson.M{"$push": "$$ROOT"},
    }},
    {"$lookup": bson.M{
        "from":         "department",
        "localField":   "_id",
        "foreignField": "dept_name",
        "as":           "department",
    }},
    {"$unwind": "$department"},
    {"$replaceRoot": bson.M{
        "newRoot": bson.M{
            "$mergeObjects": []interface{}{
                "$department",
                bson.M{"employee_list": "$employee_list"},
            },
        },
    }},
})
```

The advantage of this second approach is that it only deals with employees that have PHD (ensure there's an index for it), an only loads departments that have such employees.

Also note that it would be better practice to store the department ID in employees and not the department name, should you have to rename a department in the future, you would have to only change it in a single place (in the department document).

Comment: thanku so much it worked for me. I have one question,I have four parameters in match field so Do I have to ensure index for all?

Comment: @RajandeepKaur You should only create indices for your queries. If you never filter / query by a field, there should be no index for it.

Comment: when i send the request,everytime my result is changed. It is based on my match paramerters but sequence of result is changed like first time I get dept_id=1 result first then second time I get dept_id=2 result at first place what is the reason for that?

Comment: @RajandeepKaur An unordered / unsorted query does not guarantee any order. If you need an order, sort the results explicitly.

Comment: I want to use $skip and $limit. So where I have to write it ,after the $unwind or after the $replaceRoot

Comment: @RajandeepKaur You have too many questions for a single SO question. Feel free to create a new question.